# Why does Rashi cite Gen. 13:10 as an example at Num. 15:15, if it isn't really an example?

Tags: rashi, parashat-lech-lecha, parashat-shelach

[*Sh'lach*, 15](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%98%D7%95):1–16, speaks of the flour, oil, and wine that accompanied certain animal offerings. Verse 15 says, in part:

> חֻקַּת עוֹלָם לְדֹרֹתֵיכֶם כָּכֶם כַּגֵּר יִהְיֶה לִפְנֵי ה׳

Pretty literally:

> An eternal law for your generations; like you like the stranger shall be before God.

*Rashi* explains that last part:

> **ככם כגר** ― כמותכם כן גר וכן דרך לשון עברית כגן ה׳ כארץ מצרים כן ארץ מצרים כמוני כמוך כעמי כעמך
>
> **like you like the stranger** ― [means] "like you, so is the stranger". That's the way of Hebrew, [as in] "כגן ה׳ כארץ מצרים", [literally "like the garden of God like the land of Egypt", means "like the garden of God,] so is the land of Egypt[". Likewise,] "כמוני כמוך כעמי כעמך", [literally "like me, like you, like my nation, like your nation", means "like me, so are you; like my nation, so is your nation".]

The first quotation in *Rashi*, "כגן ה׳ כארץ מצרים", is from [*Lech L'cha* 13:10](//he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%99). (The second is from Ⅰ *Melachim* 22:4, by the way.) The problem is that *Rashi*'s explanation here in *Sh'lach* doesn't really fit the verse there in *Lech L'cha*, and, especially, doesn't fit with his own explanation there. The verse there says:

> וַיִּשָּׂא לוֹט אֶת עֵינָיו וַיַּרְא אֶת כָּל כִּכַּר הַיַּרְדֵּן כִּי כֻלָּהּ מַשְׁקֶה לִפְנֵי שַׁחֵת ה׳ אֶת סְדֹם וְאֶת עֲמֹרָה כְּגַן ה׳ כְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם בֹּאֲכָה צֹעַר
>
> Lot looked up and saw the whole Jordan plain, that it was all moist, before God's destroying Sodom and Gomorrah, like God's garden like the land of Egypt, as you come to Zoar.

Here, interpreting "כְּגַן ה׳ כְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם" as "like God's garden, so is Egypt" doesn't seem to make sense, since we're trying to describe not Egypt but the Jordan plain. And, indeed, *Rashi* interprets both "כְּגַן ה׳" and "כְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם" as comparisons to the Jordan plain, not to one another. He writes:

> **כגן ה׳** ― לאילנות
>   **כארץ מצרים** ― לזרעים
>
> **like God's garden** ― for trees
>   **like the land of Egypt** ― for seeds

Why does *Rashi* cite that verse in *Lech L'cha* as an example of the linguistic phenomenon he's describing in *Sh'lach*? It isn't one, according to him.

---

I've looked in [*Mizrachi*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40160&pgnum=531), [*L'vush*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24855&pgnum=155), and [*Gur Arye*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30845&pgnum=46) to no avail, so turn to you.

Comment: see be'er basadeh in lech-lecha and nachalas yaakov in shlach

Comment: @Jay, many thanks. I see two "באר בשדה"s on _Chumash_ at `hebrewbooks.org`: one by a סנדר פרידנברג and the other by a ברוך מרדכי פרנק. Is it one of those? And then there are many "נחלת יעקב"s; do you know the author, perchance?

Comment: No, not one of those. It was written by Rabbi Meir Dannon. Nachalas Yakov by Rabbi Yaakov Salnik. Both commentaries can be found in this set - http://seforimcenter.com/Mikraot-Gedolot-Hameorot-HaGedolim---With-11-Mefarshei-Rashi-7-vol.__p-7309.aspx - I'm not recommending to buy it at that site specifically (I don't know prices), but it is a very useful tool for understanding Rashi, with 11 commentaries on Rashi's commentary.

Comment: Riva al HaTorah (Genesis 13:10) actually notes asks this question, noting that Rashi's explanations contradict each other, and provides no solution!

Comment: @mevaqesh, [this one](//he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יצחק_בן_אשר_הלוי)?

Comment: @msh210 no R. Yehuda ben R. Eliezer. (early 14th cent.)

Comment: In this case I didn't post the Nachalas Yaakov's approach as an answer because (imo) it doesn't fit well into Rashi's words. Be'er Basadeh also finds it 'forced', and I think offers an alternate approach, but it's a long piece and I haven't had the time to go through it all.

Answer (score -1):

The citation from Lech Lecha is referring to the idea that the valley around Sodom and Gomorrah, which is called HaShem's Garden, was irrigated from the river like the man made irrigation system used in Egypt. This is in contrast to relying upon rain.

Rashi isn't making a comparison from these two citations, but only giving examples of the grammar usage of the double 'Kaf' prefix.

Comment: Citing that (_Rashi_ holds that) the Sodom area is itself called "גן ה׳" would greatly improve your answer, since that's the point that really answers my question. It certainly doesn't seem that way from the _Rashi_ in _Lech L'cha_!